# Thread safe read and instantiate a list

Tags: java, list, concurrency, thread-safety

I need to implement a list as the following:

```
private List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();

public synchronized Foo getFoo(Condition condition) {
    // loop the list and get a foo that meets the condition
    for (Foo foo: list) {
        if(condition.check(foo)) {
            return foo;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public synchronized void refresh() {
    list = new ArrayList<>(fetchFromDB());
}
```

Is there better way to avoid synchronized method to make the read and instantiate thread safe? I think CopyOnWriteArrayList won't help here because there are no mutative operations on the same list and every time we just create a new list. Am I right?

---

UPDATED: to clarify, the list will only be fully set by the refresh() method, there is no other mutation to the list.

Comment: I don't think you need synchronization. If you're not mutating, the only issue is safe publication, which you can address by making it `volatile`.

Comment: Can we assume that `list` is actually `private` and that this class contains no other methods that access or mutate the `list` variable or the `List` that it refers to?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, what you have will work.

If you don't need to coordinate the list's refresh with any other state, you could also use a `final AtomicReference<List<Foo>>`, or even use a `volatile List<Foo>`. In either of those cases, you would not need to mark your methods as `synchronized`: both [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) and `volatile` have cross-reference memory guarantees, as long as the object being assigned/set to the field isn't mutated after that assignment.

For that to work, it's crucial that the `List` isn't mutated, *and* that none of its `Foo`s are (unless they're thread-safe). If it were me, I would wrap the List in a [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) or some other unmodifiable list such as [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)), and add a comment to the effect of "this needs to be unmodifiable for thread-safety", so that someone else doesn't later change that without realizing what they're breaking. (It'll be hard to write a unit test that detects that error — more likely, you'll just hit in prod, unpredictably.)

Comment: You also don't need `volatile` if you're using `unmodifiableList()`.

Comment: @shmosel I think you'd still need it for the publication across threads, right? Not so much for the contents themselves (they're accessed internally via a `final`), but to guarantee that the other thread even sees the new reference in a timely fashion.

Comment: Good point. But the list itself is thread-safe, so it could be useful in cases where immediate visibility is not a requirement, e.g. Guava's `@LazyInit` fields.

Comment: What if there are multiple threads trying to call refresh()?

Comment: @eriee Without `synchronized`, they will both execute at the same time, and then whichever happens to write to `list` last will "win." With `synchronized`, it'll be similar except that the refreshes will all be one at a time. Either way, you may be hitting your DB more than you want, in which case you may want a separate `lastUpdated` field so you can do rate limiting. In that case, you probably do want `synchronized`, so that "check lastUpdated, fetch list, update lastUpdated is atomic.

Comment: In all of those cases, if `last` is either an AtomicReference or `volatile`, the get does not need to be synchronized; if it's neither (as in your code snippet above), it should be. But there's also no harm in having both be synchronized even if the field is AtomicReference or volatile, so if you find that easier to reason about, you should feel free to add synchronized to both!

Answer (score 4):

People have suggested using `volatile` or an `AtomicReference` as an alternative to `synchronized` or a `Lock`.

If you do this, the correctness / thread-safety will depend on *how* the `getFoo` method "loops" the list.  For example:

```
    private volatile List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Foo getFoo(Condition x) {
        for (Foo foo: list) {
           ...
        }
    }
```

will be OK because the `list` variable is read exactly once, but

```
    public Foo getFoo(Condition x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           Foo f = list.get(i);
           ...
        }
    }
```

will not be OK.  This can be addressed by assigning `list` to a local variable and iterating *that*.

Correctness / thread-safety will also depend on whether or not `getFoo` is specified to return a `Foo` that is (still) in the list when `getFoo` returns.  Consider what happens if `refresh()` is called while a `getFoo` is in progress.  If we use `synchronized` (as per the original code) then the `getFoo` returns a `Foo` that is still in the list at the point of return.  If we don't, then `getFoo` may return a list that has already been removed from the list.  Indeed, you could imagine a scenario with 3 threads like this:

```
    Thread 1 calls getFoo(c)
    Thread 2 calls refresh which empties the list
    Thread 2 refresh completes
    Thread 3 calls getFoo(c)
    Thread 3 quickly returns null because no Foo matches in the new list
    ...
    time passes
    ...
    Thread 1 returns a non-null matching Foo from the old list
```

There is also the issue of whether `list` or the `List` that it refers to can be accessed via other routes; e.g. since the example shows `list` as not declared as `private`, it could be accessed and even mutated from another class.  (This can be addressed too.)

---

Thread-safety is a surprisingly rubbery concept.  The normal definition is that code that is correct when there is only one thread is also correct in all situations where two or more threads.  In this case, "correct" means that it (provably) satisfies the formal requirements for the code.

But here we don't have either a clear statement of the formal requirements or complete versions of the code.   So therefore we cannot say **with 100% certainty** that *any* of the versions is thread-safe.

Comment: Great callout with the iteration style! And just to round it out a bit more, if someone wants to use the `for (int i=` style, they still can if they first copy the `list` to a local reference (`List<Foo> local = list`), and then iterate over that.

Comment: updated the question to make list `private` and add for-loop logic.